# CSV record insert with a MySQL check on each CSV row before inserting

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm uploading a CSV file of records to add to a MySQL database. With each row in the CSV file I need to check another MySQL table in the same database to see that the data we're entering is valid. This check is just a simple `SELECT x FROM blah WHERE primery_key = value` but with 5-10,000 records in a CSV file, it takes a long time to run through them all.

I'd like to try and make this faster, but don't know what the best options is, as none of them seem too great so far...

1. Some kind of `SELECT/INSERT FROM database WHERE IN (array created from CSV file row values)`
2. Add all the values into a new 'temporary' table, then delete the ones that don't exist in the other table via MySQL then add all the remaining records to the final table.
3. Something completely different that you fine people will enlighten me on... hopefully?

The CSV file will probably be 5000 records tops but may be as much as 10,000 in future. The table the records need to be checked against is at around 250,000 records.

Edit to add some code:

```
function processCSV($file)
    {
        if(empty($file)){
            $this->default_error[] = 'No data found';
        }

        $lines=file($file);

        foreach($lines as $line){
            $row_count++;
            $pieces = str_getcsv($line, ",");
            simple SELECT id1 FROM my_table WHERE id2 = . $pieces[0]
            if(row exists){
                puts value into array to batch process inserts at the end using array_chunk()
            }
        }
   }
```

It's not actual code as it's called from different classes, but I'm guessing all needed is there? The main issue is a MySQL check on a huge for loop, but let me know if you want more specifics.

Comment: sounds like something i do daily, but once a day at midnight, a few minutes background, its not to bad. just make sure the db's are indexed properly

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see your actual code.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [foreign key constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: temp table is easiest. then you can do a simple SINGLE join query to find the dangling/incorrects records. that'll be far more efficient than a select-per-line-in-csv

Comment: A transaction could work well here, allowing you to commit or roll back all changes at the end of your function.

Comment: thanks @eggyal, to clean up my code some more... is it possible to use foreign keys to check either one of two fields exist before inserting? In my code above it would be `WHERE id2 = $pieces[0] OR id3 = $pieces[0]`

Comment: @john: That is a strange schema.  Could you explain a little more about the structure of the referenced table?